# Calculate points coordinate in canvas by axes

Tags: android, canvas, coordinates, geometry

I need to make a rotating wheel on my android App. To do so, I'm creating a custom View in order to place it anywhere I want in the App activities. 
All around the wheel, I need to place TextViews. 
Thanks to the width and height of the view, I can get the center point of the canvas' view.
I know the angle, I know the radius, so now I need to place textviews on the edge of the circle by calculating the coordinates on the canvas.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

A point at angle theta on the circle whose center is (x0,y0) and whose radius is r is (x0 + r cos theta, y0 + r sin theta)

Or
Once you have drawn the circle you have to rotate the canvas put the text at required angle and then again restore it as,

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45, x, y);
canvas.drawText("your text here", x, y, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Hope that helps..!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. For the first solution, theta has to be in radians right ?